# Java: Append JSON Object to a JSON Object

Tags: java, json

I want to store chat history in a JSON Object, one object for each conversation, within this object i want to have an Array with all the messages.

Like this:

```
{"Channel_123":[
           {"from":"john","to":"bill", "msg":"Hello", "time":"09:57"},
           {"from":"bill","to":"john", "msg":"Hey John", "time":"09:58"}
         ]
}, {"Channel_234":[
           {"from":"bob","to":"judy", "msg":"Hello", "time":"10:37"},
           {"from":"judy","to":"bob", "msg":"Hey!", "time":"10:38"}
         ]
}
```

My current method looks like this: (the string `channel` contains the conversation id illustrated above with `Channel_234`

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject msgObj = new JSONObject();

public void addMessage(String from, String to, String msg, String time, String channel) {

    try {
        msgObj.put("from", from);
        msgObj.put("to", to);
        msgObj.put("msg", msg);
        msgObj.put("time", time);


        obj.put(channel, array);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception: ", ex);
    }

    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

But for some reason the method is not appending to the object it is overwriting what was previously there.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I am using the simple json lib: `json-simple-1.1.1.jar`

Comment: did you checkout whether the channel variable doesn't have same value???

Comment: It has a value but its being overwritten each time there is a new message, so always its just one message being saved

Comment: you have problem in create an object, each time object is recreated then only you get current value.

Comment: your key is channel variable if the channel variable has same values then they will be overwritten.. since you are not appending the data

Comment: Changing `obj.put` to `obj.append` seems to have solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the jason-simple API but you should create a new instance of `JSONObject` for each item.

```
    private JSONObject createMesssage(String form, String to, String msg, String time) throws Exception {

       JSONObject jsonMessage= new JSONObject();

            jsonMessage.put("from", from);
            jsonMessage.put("to", to);
            jsonMessage.put("msg", msg);
            jsonMessage.put("time", time);

       return jsonMessage;  

    }

  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

  private void addMessage(String channel, JSonObject messsage) throw Exception {
               obj.put(channel, message);
   }

  public void saveMessage(String form, String to, String msg, String time, Striing channel ) {

    try {
      addMessage(chanell,createMessage(form,to,msg,time));

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception: ", ex);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A valid JSON data representation won't duplicate keys in the same nesting level. Keeping in mind that only numbers, strings, null, objects and arrays are valid JSON primitives, you have some structure like:

```
[
  {
    ...
    "id_str" : "foo",
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    "id_str" : "bar",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Which is an array of JSON objects. In this case, you'd have to index the 4th element of the array and then index the "id_str" attribute of that object. Check the documentation of whatever JSON library you're using to decode the data to figure out how to do that.