# How to combine two or more JSON objects into one JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I've two JSON Objects as below

```
firstJSON: {"200":"success"} 
secondJSON: {"401":"not found"}
```

I need to combine them as `{"codes":{"200":"success"},{"401":"not found"}}` using java.

I tried in 3 ways but couldn't achieve the desired output. Could you please help with code snippet?

code which I've tried as below

```
JSONObject firstJSON = new JSONObject();
firstJSON.put("200", "success");
String firstJSONStr = firstJSON.toString();
System.out.println("firstJSONStr--> " + firstJSONStr);

JSONObject secondJSON = new JSONObject();
secondJSON.put("401", "not found");
String secondJSONStr = secondJSON.toString();
System.out.println("secondJSONStr--> "+secondJSONStr);

String finalJSONStr = firstJSONStr + "," + secondJSONStr;
JSONObject finalJSON1 = new JSONObject();
finalJSON1.put("codes", new JSONObject(finalJSONStr));
System.out.println("finalJSON1--> " + finalJSON1.toString());

JSONObject finalJSON2 = new JSONObject();
finalJSON2.put("codes", finalJSONStr);
System.out.println("finalJSON2--> " + finalJSON2.toString());

JSONObject finalJSON3 = new JSONObject();
ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonArray = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
jsonArray.add(firstJSON);
jsonArray.add(secondJSON);
finalJSON3.put("codes", jsonArray);
System.out.println("finalJSON3--> " + finalJSON3.toString());
```

Output:

```
firstJSONStr--> {"200":"success"}
secondJSONStr--> {"401":"not found"}
finalJSON1--> {"codes":{"200":"success"}}
finalJSON2--> {"codes":"{\"200\":\"success\"},{\"401\":\"not found\"}"}
finalJSON3--> {"codes":[{"200":"success"},{"401":"not found"}]}
```

Comment: this might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346790/java-append-json-object-to-a-json-object?rq=1

Comment: Note that your desired output is not valid JSON

Comment: I think the reason you are finding it difficult to get the json you require is because it simply isn't valid json: {"codes":{"200":"success"},{"401":"not found"}}. Here you have codes object {"200":"success"} and then an anonymous object {"401":"not found"}

Comment: hi folks, desired json which I'm trying to generate will be valid one

Comment: @Narasimha `{"codes":{"200":"success"},{"401":"not found"}}` Is it valid JSON ?

Comment: @varatharajan, yes it is..I've examples as well.

Comment: @Narasimha okay, show some examples. it will be helpful.

Comment: "responses": {
    "200": {
        "description": "Successful response",
        "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/GroupDetailed"
        }
    },
    "400": {
        "description": "Unrecognized quote or group ID",
        "schema": {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/UnrecognizedQuoteId"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/UnrecognizedGroupId"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

Comment: above is sample json which contains JSONObject with multiple JSONObjects

Answer (score 1):

Your expected JSON `{"codes":{"200":"success"},{"401":"not found"}}`  is invalid. You can verify it with https://jsonlint.com/ which will produce an error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 4:
...00": "success"   },  {       "401": "not foun
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', got '{'
```

You most likely want an array to group the first and second object which results in below JSON (do notice the square brackets `[` and `]`):

```
{"codes":[{"200":"success"},{"401":"not found"}]}
```

This can be achieved with:

```
JSONObject first = new JSONObject();
first.put("200", "success");

JSONObject second = new JSONObject();
second.put("401", "not found");

JSONArray codes = new JSONArray();
codes.put(first);
codes.put(second);

JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
root.put("codes", codes);

System.out.println(root);
```

Comment: @Narasimha your desired output is not a valid JSON. You can craft it manually using `StringBuilder` but no sane JSON library will let you create `{"codes":{"200":"success"},{"401":"not found"}}`

Answer (score 0):

Got the logic finally.

```
            JSONObject successJSON = new JSONObject();
            successJSON.put("description", "success");

            JSONObject scJSON = new JSONObject();
            scJSON.put("200", successJSON);



            JSONObject failJSON = new JSONObject();
            failJSON.put("description","failure");


            scJSON.put("401", failJSON);


            JSONObject finalJSON = new JSONObject();
            finalJSON.put("codes", scJSON);

            System.out.println("finalJSON --> "+finalJSON.toString());
```

Comment: output: finalJSON --> {"codes":{"200":{"description":"success"},"401":{"description":"failure"}}}